# Как правильно обрабатывать exception в PL SQL?

Tags: sql, исключения, plsql

Здравствуйте. У меня есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
select requests.phone_contact, requests.request_id 
  into l_phone, l_request_id
  from requests where requests.phone_contact = '9129766943';
exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
  dbms_output.put_line('no data');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
```

Если запрос не находит запись, то выводится и сообщение exception и сообщение ниже. Если exception не срабатывает, в консоли пусто.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как правильно обработать это исключение?
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Явно выделяйте код, ошибки которого вы хотите перехватить, и соответствующий перехват в блок begin/end. Все, что должно выполняться независимо от этого кода остается за пределами блока.

```
begin
   select requests.phone_contact, requests.request_id 
     into l_phone, l_request_id
     from requests where requests.phone_contact = '9129766943';
exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
  dbms_output.put_line('no data');
end;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test');
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так и думал, что ошибка глупая.